# Visual Studio Code "Error while fetching extensions. XHR failed"

Tags: visual-studio-code, marketplace

This problem started a few weeks ago, when I started using NordVPN on my laptop.
When I try to search for an extension and even when trying to download through the marketplace I get this error:
[image]

**EDIT:** Just noticed another thing that might indicate to what's causing the issue. When I open VSCode and go to developer tools I get this error messege (before even doing anything):

*"(node:19368) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.(Use `Code --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)"*

The only partial solution I found so far was to manually download and install extensions.

I've checked similar question here and in other places online, but I didn't find a way to fix this. So far I've tried:

1. Flushing my DNS cache and setting it to google's DNS server.
2. Disabling the VPN on my laptop and restarting VS Code.
3. Clearing the Extension search results.
4. Disabling all the extensions currently running.

I'm using a laptop running Windows 10. Any other possible solutions I haven't tried?

Comment: I was facing the same issue and I was also behind the proxy. disabling proxy worked for me.

Comment: Aleady tried disabling my VPN software @BalKrishnaJha

Comment: Just sync your Microsoft account in Vs code.

Comment: @DrewKimani's solution was the only one that helped. Recommend trying it out.

Comment: @DrewKimani. Simplest to implement and doesn't feel like a technical workaround like the other answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my case, the solution was to remove `HTTPS_PROXY` (Could be `HTTP_PROXY`) environment variable set during terminal initialisations.

Environment variables can be confirmed by `env` command for most operating systems.

I removed the line which sets the environment variable for proxy from the `bash` profile, then restarted the OS.

Apart from `~/.bashrc` for bash or any other sh-compatible shell, the environment variable could be in:

- `/etc/environment`: specifically meant for environment variables
- `/etc/env.d/*`: environment variables, split in multiple files
- `/etc/profile`: all types of initialization scripts
- `/etc/profile.d/*`: initialization scripts
- `/etc/bashrc`, `/etc/bash.bashrc`: meant for functions and aliases
- `~/.bash_profile`: initialization for login (bash-)shells
- `~/.bashrc`: initialization for all interactive (bash-)shells
- `~/.profile`: used for all shells
- `~/.cshrc`, `~/.zshrc`, `~/.tcshrc`: similar for non-bash shells

Credit to this post.
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/249922

The environment variable `HTTP(S)_PROXY` may be used by other applications. Therefore, be aware of the side effects of removing it.

Comment: This has the unwanted side effect of bricking any application that requires the https_proxy env var

Answer (score 67):

I had the same problem, I did the following steps to solve it

All you need to do is enter to the JSON settings file from VSC

```
1. Press F1
2. Type User Settings
3. Search for Proxy
4. In proxy section, look for the title `Http: Proxy Authorization`
5. Click on 'Edit in settings.json'
6. Delete all brackets containing proxy data
7. Save JSON file
```

After that, just restart VSC
You can also find the JSON in `%appdata%/Code/User/settings.json`

Comment: Tried it but it didn't help...

Comment: Didn't work on arch linux

Comment: This worked for me on Windows, on a machine that does not have a proxy.

However, I had to delete the entire line (e.g. the key and the value, which was set to null)

Comment: worked like a charm for me, I just removed the proxy witch I believe was set by a virus

Comment: Worked for me on Linux Mint 20 and VSC 1.69.0. I deleted the "default" value block and saved "settings.json".
But be careful : when I launched again VSC it reopened the "settings.json" (I had not closed the tab) and added again the "default" value...
In this case, close the file without saving and it will keep the workaround working.

Comment: the key for me was to restart VSCode

Comment: In Windows 10, I had to remove my system environment variables that were setting the proxy.

Comment: my intellisense is back, that's what i wanted, though i still can't install any extensions.

Comment: works on macos 12.6.1 without restarting ide

Answer (score 45):

so i find this

1. press f1
2. search user setting
3. click enter
4. search on user setting " proxy "
5. click enter
6. look for "use the proxy support for extensions."
7. change override to on

maybe this can help you.

Comment: changed from "override" -> "fallback", it works

Answer (score 23):

For me , 'XHR failed' error appears when the proxy settings between your PC system and vs code are conflict.

1.Check PC system proxy settings.

2.Open cmd or terminal, type

`echo %http_proxy%`, if any output, make sure it fits your pc proxy setting. Because if the proxy on vs code not being set, will be inherited from the `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` environment variables.

3.If none, open vs code settings.json , add
`"http.proxy":"http://proxyname:port"` that fits your pc proxy setting ,without a trailing slash.

Try download extensions again.Hope this helps. ^^

Comment: You can also open code with `--ignore-certificate-errors`, install the extensions, then restart without the flag.

Answer (score 23):

Simply follow below steps:

1. Press F1
2. Type User Settings
3. Search for "Proxy Authorization"
4. Click on "Edit in settings.json"
5. Add new key value pair - "http.proxySupport": "on"
6. Save JSON file

At my end settings.json file

```
{
    "http.proxyAuthorization": null,
    "http.proxySupport": "on"
}
```

Answer (score 19):

I don't use a proxy, and I do use NextDNS so I didn't want to change my DNS settings.

As a workaround, you can open code with `--ignore-certificate-errors` flag, install any extensions, then restart without the flag.

On windows:

```
code --ignore-certificate-errors
```

Comment: This works on linux debian 11 as well.

Answer (score 5):

This is an issue with the proxy setting.

- Press F1
- Type User Settings
- Search for "Proxy"
- Http:Proxy will be empty
- Add your proxy here with http://username:password@SERVER:PORT

And just restart visual studio code

Comment: Collaborating with this answer. Change this example `https://10.1.33.254:80` into `https://:@10.1.33.254:80`. In my case, I was not requested username and password, that's why the `//:@` part is empty.

Comment: Http:Proxy had a value from previous work with Fiddler. 
I needed to remove the value and set Http:Proxy back to blank.

Answer (score 3):

In my case `http_proxy` `system environment` variable was set in Windows 10. After deleting that VS code started loading extensions.

Comment: this was my issue also.  I deleted the http_proxy & https_proxy environment variables & the error went away

Answer (score 3):

Following worked for me :

- press f1
- search user setting
- click enter search on user setting " proxy "
- click enter
- remove the value present in "Http: Proxy"

Answer (score 2):

December 10,2021.
I'm using vscode with ubuntu 20.04.
I came across the XHR errors from yesterday and could not install any extensions.
Googled a lot but nothing works.
Eventually I downloaded and installed the newest version of VSCode(deb version) and everything is fine now.
(I don't know why but maybe you can give it a try! Good Luck!)

Comment: I'm using windows. Tried to update the version and I even unistalled it and then reinstalled it's still showing the same error

Comment: This solved it for me. Just restarting VS Code hadn't solved the issue so it was the upgrade that did it. (And I'm not behind a corporate proxy).

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error with the .deb version from the visualstudio.com page.

Have you tried opening the Developer Tools (F1, Developer Tools). Which error is returned?
I had ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID. The --ignore-certificate-errors command-line flag is a workaround for me (as indicated here https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/network).

Comment: Checked the dev tools. I'm getting: ERR_PROXY_CONNECTION_FAILED

Comment: So I assume you are behind a proxy.
This page will help you to find you proxy settings: https://www.browserstack.com/local-testing/proxy-settings-for-local-testing-parameters
This page will help you to configure VSCode: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/network

Answer (score 2):

As far as I am aware the XHR error has several possible causes. The easiest fix which should be attempted prior to more complicated methods is restarting VS Code.

I have seen this error a couple of times and have been able to resolve it this way, for me it was not related to proxy settings, whereas for other users it might be. A possible relevant scenario is running a VS Code instance without restart or update over prolongued periods of time, such as days or even weeks.

Answer (score 2):

[image: For me i had to disable this option from Visual Studio Code.]

For me i had to disable this option from Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 2):

Running Windows 11, it is Windows Firewall preventing it.

1. Open Windows Security
2. Click on Firewall & Network Security
3. Click on Allow an app through the firewall
4. Click on Change Settings
5. Click on Allow Another App
6. Browse to where VS Code is installed and click on Code.exe
7. Make sure that Code shows in the list of the allowable apps

And that is it

Hope it works with you as well.

S.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, just only sign in with Microsoft Account works for me according to [Drew Kimani](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70177216/visual-studio-code-error-while-fetching-extensions-xhr-failed/75808624?noredirect=1#comment126402808_70177216) comment on this question.

1. Open VS Code, click profile logo then click `Turn On Cloud Changes`
   [image: step 1]
2. Choose `Sign In with Microsoft` and follow the next steps.
   [image: step 2]

After done, it will resolve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using windows 11 and I was having the same issue.
My laptop has a Killer wifi board and it comes with a option to "enable game fast". It was checked to start automatically with a game. I just unchecked it and this error stopped to show up.

I hope your problem will be easy as mine to solve. Try maybe your firewall.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same issue. And I delete the .vscode-server directory in server. Reconnect my server successful.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue .. it's a very specific solution that worked for me but I hope it helps someone who will pass by here in the future:

Apparently .. I disconnected ***Cloudflare Zero Trust "Warp 1.1.1.1"*** in the CLI by mistake and some applications (vscode,firefox,skype ..) were using it .. so all I had to do was reconnect .. if your warp tray icon doesn't work like mine then all you have to do is type the command:

```
warp-cli connect
```

And all was back to working.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem, however no proxy or VPN.
Solved it by entirely erasing my vscode config folders: %appdata%\Code and %userprofile%\.vscode. (As explained in https://stackoverflow.com/a/75473624/2381133.)

Comment: Actually, this only worked for a few minutes (to install a single extension). Afterwards, solved it by allowing code.exe through the Windows firewall, as Sami Tarazi explains in https://stackoverflow.com/a/74290335/2381133.

Answer (score 0):

In my **Windows** machine deleting **http_proxy** User Environment Variable helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Using the task manager I noticed that I had another vscode-instance running that was not closed properly.
Shutting every vscode instance down using the Task manager, restarting it I got two vscode-windows, closed one, could install in the remaining one.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows 11 with @binjie-liang answer, in your windows search for proxy settings and toggle off the **Automatically Detect Settings**. This will resolve the issue. Should be same with windows 10 also

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in linux,

Manually downloading did not work with an error like: "Request was blocked due to exceeding usage of resource 'Count' in namespace AnnonymousID ..." (I did not save the full message unfortunately). I think Network speed was not an issue because my collage who was connected to same network was able to download extensions.

closing all instances of vscode and re-opening solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I just restarted my entire computer and it worked.

I hate to have this dumb answer. But, I did look into most of the other answers. When something smells like a network issue and you "didn't change anything", it can be many things.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check if http_proxy is set as an environment variable and delete that line if set and no longer on a network that has proxy set-up.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For me,it suddenly started working after 4 hours. I don't know if the problem was from my ISP or VSCode Extension server, but it somehow solved itself.

Answer (score -1):

I have had the same issue on Debian 10 and fixed it by downgrading VSCode to an older version 1.33.1.

Comment: I'd rather not downgrade. Some of the extensions I'm using only work on more dated versions.

Answer (score -1):

I faced this problem in 7-2022, and it's gone without even restart vscode.
The reason was poor internet connection. If this is ur situation check the quality of your internet connection and just click refresh button, then extensions appear after a moment!

Answer (score -1):

I had same error: while fetching extensions xhr failed visual studio code on Mac and Windows.

VPN solved my problems.

Answer (score -1):

Same problem, easy solution: just login to Microsoft account and sync settings.

At least try this before all the other more complicated things?

Comment: The"?" confuses me and the system mechanisms which scan for inappropriate/off-topic posts.

Answer (score -1):

Same problem, updated VS Code on mac while connected to the VPN. After the update I got the XHR Error.

The solution was to stop the VPN, connect to the host and then reconnect the VPN and it seems to work normally. For now.

Answer (score -1):

For me the problem was just that my proxy server was on, in my Windows machine. I was earlier working with network tracing, and it seemed to be causing the error.

**Problem message:**

[image: Problem message]

**Solution: resetting proxy settings**

[image: Proxy server settings in windows 11]

So I just turned off everything in proxy settings or you can reset it to default.