# VS code error installing extensions net::ERR_PROXY_CONNECTION_FAILED

Tags: visual-studio-code, proxy

I'm trying to install an extension on my VS code, but I can't seem to access the marketplace from VS code. It's working fine from the browser but when I try accessing it from VS Code I get

```
"Error while fetching extensions, XHR failed"
```

When I toggle the developer options and check the console it says

```
net::ERR_PROXY_CONNECTION_FAILED
```

And as you can imagine, since I'm asking this, it means I've tried most of the options I could find on stack overflow and otherwise

Maybe I'm setting it up all wrong

my settings.json file is as follows

```
{
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Monokai",
    "http.proxyStrictSSL": false,
    "http.proxyAuthorization": null,
    "http.proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:61575",
    "https.proxy": "https://127.0.0.1:61575"
}
```

Perhaps I've configured something incorrectly, I just don't know what.

it worked in the past

Please help. Thanks

Comment: you can download the extension from the marketplace and use the **Install from VSIX** menu option from the Extension bar (top `...` menu)

Comment: Probably talk to your network administrators. In a company network, it is not a surprise to see VSCode Marketplace blocked.

Comment: If your problem is to install the extension, this might help : https://stackoverflow.com/a/71824900/18048269

Answer (score 0):

This is how I managed to solve it on windows and Linux ubuntu
Open terminal then run `code --ignore-certificate-errors`
*this will just open vscode*
Then try installing you can also restart your vscode
Goodluck