# Visual Studio stalling python extension on m1 Macbook

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I tried to install and manually install the Microsoft python extension, both not working. I have installed python 3.9.7 on my m1 macbook.

After I click "installing", then the following error message appears:
[image]

And in the log:
[image]

Also when I tried to install manually via the vsix file:

[image]

In the log it appears:
[image]
What is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many possible causes for XHR errors. You can refer to [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70177216/visual-studio-code-error-while-fetching-extensions-xhr-failed), and I think the easiest way is to **restart or reinstall vscode**.