# VS code failed to load extensions and failed to install new extension after an update

Tags: vscode-extensions, failed-installation

Today I reopen my VS Code after several days, found the extensions that I installed and used for a long time disappeared totally, and it recommended me to install extension for java. OK, I followed the recommends to install extension, and failed.

I checked my Code version, it's the latest version surely.
Then I dipped into the log and tried to install some other extensions, and found the failure always related to one js file `sharedProcessMain.js`. The detail log is as following:

```
2023-02-16 09:32:06.725 [error] SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.factory (vscode-file://vscode-app/d:/Users/MI/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:88:93520)
2023-02-16 09:32:06.771 [error] Unexpected end of JSON input: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.factory (vscode-file://vscode-app/d:/Users/MI/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:88:93520)
```

If anyone who can provide any suggestion? Thank you very much!

Comment: In edge cases, VS Code does corrupt itself and you have to fully reinstall it (cleaning up the corruption) in such cases.

Comment: I tried, but not work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On what OS are you running?

I use Windows and I faced the same problem yesterday. Solved it by

1. Closing VSCode
2. Removing the entire folder %appdata%\Code
3. Removing the entire folder %userprofile%\.vscode
4. Starting VSCode

Hope this helps.

Comment: Actually, this only worked for a few minutes (to install a single extension). Afterwards, solved it by allowing code.exe through the Windows firewall, as Sami Tarazi explains in https://stackoverflow.com/a/74290335/2381133.