# Extensions not installing

Tags: vscode-extensions

I tried all the steps shown in different web sites to install extensions in my VSCode 1.70.2. I am using Windows 7 Ultimate SP1. I am unable to install any extension and get this error "XHR failed". I connect Internet using my Android Phone's Internet in my PC. I recently formatted my PC, before it was working well.

Help me to solve the problem.

I tried all the steps shown in different web sites. But all in vain.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio Code "Error while fetching extensions. XHR failed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70177216/visual-studio-code-error-while-fetching-extensions-xhr-failed)

Answer (score 0):

1. Check for Proxy Settings, Antivirus or Firewall, something might be blocking VS Code from accessing the internet.
2. You can also manually install extensions [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-marketplace).
3. It's also worth noting that Windows 7 is no longer officially supported by Microsoft, and this could potentially cause compatibility issues with newer versions of VS Code and its extensions.