# vsc "Error while fetching extensions. XHR failed."

Tags: visual-studio-code, proxy

I can't even look up extensions on vsc.
[this is the errore that appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Tu1N.jpg)
I've had this problem for a few years now, after a prof of mine had me use commands to set up the proxy, I just don't remember what command it is honestly.

I've seen that others have asked about this problem, and even following the "tutorials" on what to do, I can't solve the problem.
i don't use any kind of vpn and i took the proxy out of windows settings and vsc settings, but nothing changes, even going to edit the json file.
[this is the link i mainly looked at](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70177216/visual-studio-code-error-while-fetching-extensions-xhr-failed)
i have tried following the directions of many of the answers they gave and nothing changes, do you know why else it might be giving me this problem

Comment: this question has been asked many many times already: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Error+while+fetching+extensions.+XHR+failed.%22+is%3Aq+%5Bvscode%5D