VS code extension not loading
After installing VS Code, I do not get the extensions, Rather, I receive the error

error while fetching extension.

I have tried every means to resolve it, but to no avail. Could you please assist me.
I want it that after installing VS Code, I will be able to navigate to the extensions

Try: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70177216/visual-studio-code-error-while-fetching-extensions-xhr-failed ?
